# CQL query delete if not in list

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0, cql3

I am trying to delete all rows in the table where the partition key is not in a list of guids.

Here's my table definition.

```
CREATE TABLE cloister.major_user (
    user_id uuid,
    user_handle text,
    avatar text,
    created_at timestamp,
    email text,
    email_verified boolean,
    first_name text,
    last_name text,
    last_updated_at timestamp,
    profile_type text,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, user_handle)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (user_handle ASC)
```

I want to retain certain user_ids and delete the rest. The following options have failed.

```
delete from juna_user where user_id ! in (0d70272c-8d24-43d0-9b2d-c62100b0e28e,0b7c0841-3a18-4c03-a211-f75690c93815,e96ba860-72cf-44d5-a6bd-5a9ec58827e3,729d7973-d4c4-42fb-94c4-d1ffd03b74cd,3bffa0c6-8b98-4f0c-bd7c-22d0662ab0a2)

delete from juna_user where user_id not in (0d70272c-8d24-43d0-9b2d-c62100b0e28e,0b7c0841-3a18-4c03-a211-f75690c93815,e96ba860-72cf-44d5-a6bd-5a9ec58827e3,729d7973-d4c4-42fb-94c4-d1ffd03b74cd,3bffa0c6-8b98-4f0c-bd7c-22d0662ab0a2)

delete from juna_user where user_id not in (0d70272c-8d24-43d0-9b2d-c62100b0e28e,0b7c0841-3a18-4c03-a211-f75690c93815,e96ba860-72cf-44d5-a6bd-5a9ec58827e3,729d7973-d4c4-42fb-94c4-d1ffd03b74cd,3bffa0c6-8b98-4f0c-bd7c-22d0662ab0a2) ALLOW FILTERING
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

CQL supports only `IN` condition (see [docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlDelete.html#cqlDelete__row-specification)).  You need to explicitly specify which primary key or partition keys to delete, you can't use condition `not in`, because it's potentially could be a huge amount of data.  If you need to do that, you need to generate the list of entries to delete - you can do that using [Spark Cassandra Connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/tree/master/doc), for example.

Comment: I guess the answer is that it can't be done via cql and needs to be done via a script or a program.

Comment: yes, this can't be done in CQL.  Cassandra is distributed system, and using of `not in` will require scanning of all data to find what not in the given list